# System.ArgumentException: No member matching data has been found - Unity IOC

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mvvm, unity-container

I getting exception in my application while executing at line

```
public static void Initialize(Context applicationContext, IUnityContainer diContainer)
{
    diContainer.RegisterType<IAndroidGlobals, AndroidGlobals>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(applicationContext));
}
```

This is AndroidGlobls Class

```
public class AndroidGlobals : IAndroidGlobals
{

    public string ApplicationVersion(string appName)
    {
        return  ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(appName, 0).VersionName;
    }
    public Android.Content.Context ApplicationContext
    {
        get { return _applicationContext; }
    }

    private readonly Context _applicationContext;

    public AndroidGlobals(Context applicationContext)
    {
        _applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Below is the exception. How can I solve this issue

> {System.InvalidOperationException: No member matching data has been
>   found.   Error in: 
>   RegisterType(Lifetime:PerContainer,
>   Invoke.Constructor(dispatch.droid.mainactivity@77cb316))  --->
>   System.ArgumentException: No member matching data has been found.   at
>   Unity.Injection.InjectionConstructor.SelectMember (System.Type type,
>   Unity.Injection.InjectionMember _) [0x0003c] in
>   C:\projects\abstractions\src\Dependency\Injection\Members\InjectionConstructor.cs:48
>   at
>   Unity.Injection.InjectionMember`2[TMemberInfo,TData].AddPolicies[TContext,TPolicySet]
>   (System.Type registeredType, System.Type mappedToType, System.String
>   name, TPolicySet& policies) [0x00023] in
>   C:\projects\abstractions\src\Dependency\Injection\Abstracts\InjectionMember.cs:133
>   at Unity.UnityContainer.Unity.IUnityContainer.RegisterType
>   (System.Type typeFrom, System.Type typeTo, System.String name,
>   Unity.Lifetime.ITypeLifetimeManager lifetimeManager,
>   Unity.Injection.InjectionMember[] injectionMembers) [0x00144] in
>   C:\projects\container\src\UnityContainer.IUnityContainer.cs:66     ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
>   Unity.UnityContainer.Unity.IUnityContainer.RegisterType (System.Type
>   typeFrom, System.Type typeTo, System.String name,
>   Unity.Lifetime.ITypeLifetimeManager lifetimeManager,
>   Unity.Injection.InjectionMember[] injectionMembers) [0x002de] in
>   C:\projects\container\src\UnityContainer.IUnityContainer.cs:97    at
>   Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType[TFrom,TTo]
>   (Unity.IUnityContainer container, Unity.Lifetime.ITypeLifetimeManager
>   lifetimeManager, Unity.Injection.InjectionMember[] injectionMembers)
>   [0x00000] in
>   C:\projects\abstractions\src\Extensions\Container\UnityContainer.cs:132
>   at Ex.Express.Mobile.Core.Shared.Initializer.Initialize
>   (Android.Content.Context applicationContext, Unity.IUnityContainer
>   diContainer) [0x00012] in
>   D:\ExNew\SmartPad\DEV\Ex.Express.Mobile\SmartPad\Components\Core\Core.Shared\Initializer.cs:72
>   at Ex.Express.Mobile.Core.Droid.Initializer.Initialize
>   (Android.Content.Context applicationContext, Unity.IUnityContainer
>   diContainer) [0x00001] in
>   D:\ExNew\SmartPad\DEV\Ex.Express.Mobile\SmartPad\Components\Core\Core.Droid\Initializer.cs:22
>   at Ex.Express.Mobile.Apps.DispatchApp.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate
>   (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00034] in
>   D:\ExNew\SmartPad\DEV\Ex.Express.Mobile\SmartPad\Apps\Messages\DispatchApp.Droid\MainActivity.cs:121
>   }

I am using `Sdk and User Assembly` in linker. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved by using attribute `[Android.Runtime.Preserve(AllMembers = true)]` at the top of all used classes.